# Retrofit subsequent calls not working

Tags: android, retrofit

I have something like this

```
Retrofit retrofit =new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("URL")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

         requestService = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
         call = requestService.getData(page);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cats>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Cats>> call, Response<List<Cats>> response) {
                ....

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Cats>> call, Throwable t) {

            ...
            }
        });
```

However when i want to get the second page, when i make a request for the second page within the same class, retrofit callback methods is not getting called.

`call = requestService.getData(page);` // page incremnted

call and requestService  is globally defined

Comment: can you post fully code ?

Comment: you can put a break point to see if the class code executes and besides see the logs if there are any exceptions

Comment: @Raghunandan there are no exception, First call is working. when  onScrollStateChanged is called, i dont see,  onResponse getting called. Plz see updated qn

Comment: I think it has something to do with reusing retrofit call. If i delete the line and create a brand new retofitservice to call the second page, its working

Comment: @32a are you creating a new retrofit service instance every time before making a request? Please share the exact method definition where you are making the call.

Comment: @Udit no, if i do, it seems to be working. but its inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Retrofit, each "call" instance is linked to one API call (single network request) and cannot be reused. You can reuse your RetrofitSerive instance, but for every new API call you will have to create a new Call object and enqueue it separately

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I don't know how to create a new call object and enqueue it separately...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic response and use an url each time.

```
@GET
Call<Generic<T>> getUsers(@Url String url);
```